# Error in my car loan papers, what do I do?

Tags: banking, credit, car, auto-loan, mistakes

In Dec 2014 I turned in a financed car that I had where my mom was the Primary Owner and I was the cosigner and I purchased a new car only under my name and credit, my mother wasn't present and she didn't sign any paper or anything.
The loan was acquired through the same bank as before.

Later in I realized that;

- The loan doesn't appear on my credit report and does appear under my mom's one.
- The loan bank started sending my correspondence about the car loan in which they use my First Name with my Mother's Last Name
- They send correspondence to my mom using her First Name and My Last Name!
- Also, this bank is where my mom has her personal bank account, and they changed her info to make My Last Name as hers so now she appears with My Last Name in all her bank info

What can I do with all these mistakes?
Thanks!

Comment: To speculate, the bank probably changed your mom's name because, as the primary owner of the traded car, your mom should have been present for the transaction.  They're probably assuming your mom simply signed with a different name, so they "updated" her name.  Just call the bank.

Comment: Wow I hadn't thought about that in that way, I will contact them thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The absolute first thing you need to do is contact the bank. Also, do you have a copy of the loan papers you signed? You should look over those as soon as possible as well. I'm sure you want these payments going toward your FICO score and not your mothers.

Comment: Hi @lucasdavis500 thanks for your quick response. Yes my loan papers are all under my name and not my mothers. I dont really mind where are the payments going in terms of the FICO score because I have a great credit despite of this matter. But I wanted to know if eith this great mistake that the bank has done of mixing up our names and putting the car under my mothers name without her signing any paper we can apply the law of erasing debts when they have errors on the Credit reports?

Comment: I don't want to comment on how to apply any law to your situation. However, I do believe if you have your copy of the contract and it is the bank's mistake, and no where does it state your mother is the proprietor of the loan, then the bank will take care of it.